# While installing tomcat 7 manually I am facing this issue

Tags: tomcat7

To install tomcat7 I have done:

```
a. downloaded apache-tomcat7 tar.gz file
b. extracted in /usr/share directory
c. starting tomcat using /usr/share/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
getting message: 

    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
    Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Tomcat started.
```

but when I am going through the URL : localhost:8080 it is saying unable to connect.
Can somebody help me out from this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any other application is holding the port:8080.

Locally tomcat points to 8080 and if any other applicationis running on that port then Tomcat won't start. Tomcat 7 is not an issue here.

The main culprit on your machine may be Skype. check in the processes and kill it and try the url again. Use an open source tool called Diamond port to check which processes are running on 8080

Comment: Using this command sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':8080'
    it is showing that no service is running on port 8080.

Comment: I haven't installed Skype too.

Comment: have you manually set CATALINA_HOME in your environment variables and added it to the path variable there. also check JAVA_HOME variable and version compatibilty between the two

Comment: Yes I have given catalina_home manually in .bashrc file.
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle 
    export JAVA_HOME

    CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
    export CATALINA_HOME
what can be the wrong here?

Comment: did you try to start the tomcat server using the startup.bat. did it start without any error before you tried with the url. sorry your log shows that. but can you check the compatibility of Tomcat 7 with the Linux machine. may be a system bit configuration of the downloaded Tomcat version

Comment: I am using startup.sh to start the tomcat and it is giving message "Tomcat started". But in browser it's not working.

Comment: may be version could be the problem. let me try with older version

Comment: I installed apache6 and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Yup, I am creating Syncope project. Thanks for helping me.